# sql server installation errors regarding WMI service

Tags: sql-server, wmi

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 and during the pre requisite check its always fails on 
WMI service "Failed".
I went to the event viewer and found this error in there.
"Failed to Initialize WMI Core or Provider SubSystem or Event SubSystem with error number 0x80040154. This could be due to a badly installed version of WMI, WMI repository upgrade failure, insufficient disk space or insufficient memory."

I know there is a lot of space available in my hard drive. Also i tried a few things after googling like WMIFIX.bat file. The file ran fine but did not fix the problem.
Has anyone had this problem? If so do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the WMI Diag Utility.  Here are the instructions how to do this:

[Download WMIDiag](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=99639).

To run the WMIDiag tool:
  1. Open a command prompt window.
     (Use "Run As Administrator", if applies to your Operating System version)
  2. Navigate to the wmidiag folder that was created when you ran Wmidiag.exe.
  3. Type `cscript wmidiag.vbs`.

View what the output of that is and post what it says.  That'll give you a better indication of what's happening.

[Here is a reference for the above instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775015%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: i read the error log report and first of all its huge, also i dont really see what to do since it doesnt say which services dont work. Also I'm using Vista 32bit if that helps

Answer (score 3):

if you have a domain so Run this Command with administrator Privilege

### you can copy this Command and Past in Notbat with .bat extention. and run them.

```
Rundll32 setupapi,InstallHinfSection Ndi-Steelhead 132 %windir%\inf\netrass.inf
Netsh firewall reset
sc config SharedAccess obj= LocalSystem password= "" type= interact type= own
sc config RpcSs obj= LocalSystem password= "" type= interact type= own
sc config RpcLocator obj= LocalSystem password= "" type= interact type= own
sc config winmgmt obj= LocalSystem password= "" type= interact type= own
sc config Wmi obj= LocalSystem password= "" type= interact type= own
net start winmgmt
net start Wmi
net start RpcSs
net start RpcLocator
net start WmiApSrv
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 135 "Open Port 135"
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 445 "Open Port 445"
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 139 "Open Port 139"
netsh firewall set opmode mode=DISABLE
shutdown /r
```

---

if your problem did not solve you Can execute this Command in Command Prompt with admin privilege.. you can just copy  and paste them in notepad and rename it with .bat extention an run the file..

---

```
net stop winmgmt
C:
cd %systemroot%\system32\wbem

rd /S /Q repository

regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\scecli.dll
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\userenv.dll

mofcomp cimwin32.mof
mofcomp cimwin32.mfl
mofcomp rsop.mof
mofcomp rsop.mfl
for /f %%s in ('dir /b /s *.dll') do regsvr32 /s %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.mof') do mofcomp %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.mfl') do mofcomp %%s
echo DONE reboot
```

### pause

just it and have a good day  !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I tried to install SQL Express

For me, following steps worked out which I referred from http://mikeymurph.me/fix-wmi-service-error/

Run the following in Powershell in Administrator mode

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winmgmt /verifyrepository
WMI repository verification failed
Error code:     0x80041002
Facility:       WMI
Description:    Not found

PS C:\Windows\system32> Winmgmt /resetrepository
WMI repository has been reset
```

Now try to install SQL Server again.